# Are these answers really « bad »?

Tags: discussion

I've been on SO for a while now and I've always assumed that a "bad" answer is an one that does not provide anything useful to answer the problem (or that provide false or already given information).

But this morning, I felt on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871848/how-to-sum-list-tuples-in-python), which has currently 4 answers (it had 5 a while ago), 3 of which are downvoted by @juanchopanza, the fourth one being its own answer.

While I agree that his answer is the best one regarding the currently available information in the question, I do not understand the need of downvoting (and denigrate) the other answers.

Are these answers so "bad"? Isn't it allowed to provide an answer which is not "perfect"?

The first time I cam on that question, the only available answer was by [Steven Kryskalla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75956/steven-kryskalla), and my first though was "Okay, it is a correct answer, I will simply add a comment saying that the temporary list is useless." (which would have made his answer equivalent to the one of @juanchopanza). Instead of that, should I have downvoted his answer and write my own, simply changing one line of his?

Maybe, as @juanchopanza say, I don't understand the voting system very well, so I hope someone will be able to clarify things for me...

Comment: how do you know that answers are downvoted by @juanchopanza?

Comment: Everyone is entitled to their own opinion and votes, provided they are not based on the person but on the post. This means both you and juanchopanza are also allowed to disagree on what makes an answer downvote-worthy.

Comment: @Neel: given the comments it is a fair assumption that they voted those posts.

Comment: Isn't the bigger problem that we have (currently) six users rushing answer a trivial question with no visible effort on the part of the OP?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: And yet, the person *commenting* and the person *downvoting* are quite frequently not the same person. I get this a lot: People thinking I downvoted their answer when what I did was comment on it. There are lots of reasons not to comment when downvoting, and a lot of people don't. There are lots of reasons to comment without downvoting, and a lot of people do. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree with you, but in this case, the content of the comments and answers, and the timing of these downvotes made things a bit clearer. But even if my assumption are wrong, the question remains.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I agree, it is not something you can rely on 100%.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree. In retrospect, maybe I shouldn't have answered. The only reason I did is because there was a barrage of over-complicated answers and I wanted to show OP a simple solution that was equivalent to all but one of the answers. Maybe I should have just have left a comment.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ["people... posting crap, not searching for dupes when they should, and behaving like hyenas just to get some extra points..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all#comment798506_244290)

Comment: I downvoted this question arbitrarily, however my action has now rendered it « bad » and so it should be removed.  Never mind the fact that the downvote has actually nothing to do with the quality of the question, and everything to do with my piles acting up.

Comment: I've been on both sides of that: I've commented right when someone else voted and I've voted only to see a critical comment pop-up at the same time. It is not a safe assumption that a comment and a vote occurring at the same time implies that the same person did both, especially for questions at the top of the new/popular/needs answer/tag lists or currently being discussed on meta.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I guess it is not worth to point to someone if you are just having the assumption.

Secondly, the voting system is totally based on opinions of the person who is voting and downvotes ought never to require explanation.

Everyone has right to downvote if he/she thinks it could be better than this, OR if something is going in the wrong direction according to OP's current question, OR if something might be misguiding, OR if something might be wrongly written.

So instead of rushing for "Reputation" we all should concentrate on providing the best answer which can be useful not just for the OP but everyone who reads it!

I guess you need to understand that if a person down votes your answer it DOES NOT make your answer bad. there are lost of other people which will up vote your answer if it is worth getting up votes. We can never assume what a person thinking while down voting so better try to give your best and don't bother for the down vote BUT if your answer is lacking and you get the same from multiple people then you need to look at your answer again to improve .

Comment: So it is better to downvote a "almost" good answer and provide an answer with a tiny modification than to post a comment on this "almost" good answer to show which improvement could be made?

Comment: @Holt: the *guideline* is to vote on how helpful an answer is. I personally wouldn't downvote an answer just because it could still be better (a almost good answer). But everyone is allowed their own standards as to what makes an answer helpful.

Comment: see @Holt I guess you need to understand that if a person down votes your answer it DOES NOT make your answer bad. there are lost of other people which will up vote your answer if it is worth getting up votes. We can never assume what a person thinking while down voting so better try to give your best and don't bother for the down vote BUT if your answer is lacking and you get the same from multiple people then you need to look at your answer again to improve .

Comment: @MartijnPieters And so a question that is not the "perfect" one is not useful? I mean, if the answer is correct and provide a working solution for the problem, why should it be downvoted? I have to admit that I am really confused on this point...

Comment: @Holt: again, the votes are a *personal opinion*. We are also *speculating* here as to why the posts  were downvoted. See [Should 'drive by' downvoting be more effectively caught?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397) What I am saying is that the votes may suck, but they are 'valid' votes in that they are allowed.

Comment: @Holt I didn't judge any of those answers to be "almost good". Voting has a subjective element, but I think I am fair, and I would be happy for people to vote on my posts in the same way. If I post a clanger, I prefer it if someone down-votes it so I can learn from it. Many users seem to double down instead. There seems to be an expectation that every answer is OK.